# Check who changed permissions on file/item level in document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, permissions, document

We have dozen of users with full permissions in one of document libraries.
Somebody is changing user permissions on document/item level occasionally.
Is it possible to see somewhere in logs or anywhere/anyhow who is doing it?

> exp. There are 4 office docs in library and they are all inheriting
>   permissions from parent, document library. From time to time, one or
>   two documents are set to unique permissions with some groups removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it if Auditing on the Site collection is enabled. Otherwise it is very hard to find, because you have to dig into the ULS logs and IIS logs to get the clue.You can check it if it enabled and user permission auditing is checked.

Go to `Site settings> Site Collection Administration> select Site collection audit settings` and on this page make Sure **Editing users and permissions** is selected.

to view the report `Site settings> Site Collection Administration> Audit log reports` You will see the security Settings report. open it and examine.

[Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-A9920C97-38C0-44F2-8BCB-4CF1E2AE22D2)

Comment: thank you very much on your reply. but I didn't find actions that would solve question who edited permissions. note: Auditing was already enabled so it's not that.

Comment: After another filter, colleague found what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this article..
https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/125875-how-to-find-permission-changes-in-sharepoint-2013-site-collection